# Kubernetes container won't set Request resources (CPU & RAM) properly

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to set a *fixed* resource value to my [kubernetes container](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go). When I try the following:

```
//cont = v1.Container
log.Println("Before", cont.Resources.Requests.Memory())
cont.Resources.Requests.Memory().SetMilli(512) //new wanted value
log.Println("After", cont.Resources.Requests.Memory())

log.Println("Before", cont.Resources.Requests.Cpu())
cont.Resources.Requests.Cpu().SetScaled(2, resource.Giga) //new wanted value
log.Println("After", cont.Resources.Requests.Cpu())
```

I get this:

```
Before 0
After 0
Before 0
After 0
```

Why doesn't `Set` update my values to the newer ones? How can I set the CPU & RAM resources properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Dim's answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57203), I managed to find a solution. It seems that when [resources](https://github.com/dims/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/resource.go#L36-L42) are not set, one cannot set the new value in the data structure returned by Memory(). The proper way to do it is this:

```
cont.Resources.Requests = make(map[v1core.ResourceName]resource.Quantity)
cont.Resources.Requests[v1core.ResourceMemory] = *resource.NewQuantity(int64(512), resource.BinarySI)
cont.Resources.Requests[v1core.ResourceCPU] = *resource.NewQuantity(int64(4), resource.BinarySI)
```

Cheers!